# flash plugin for firefox 9.0.1 Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, flash, firefox-extensions

Problem:
I can play flash videos locally, in chromium, and in epiphany (the GNOME web browser). For some reason support is spotty in firefox. Youtube will play most of the time but sometimes the video loads in a much smaller frame. Other sites with flash video or flash games rarely load. Occasionally the very same page will fail to load but succeed on refresh. Other pages will give me a link to install flash player. I can't find a pattern at all. I suspect a plugin conflict but looking at the plugin manager in preferences, I don't see one.

System info:
Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit *and* 64-bit)
flash 11.1

Comment: 32 bit? 64 bit? Which version of Flash?

Comment: Sorry about that. Added update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the flash plugin in the correct place manually.

I created a folder under ~/.mozilla/plugins - (.mozilla is a hidden folder in your home directory) and copied the libflashplayer.so file from [ADOBE](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) (it's in the installer .tar.gz)

Double check that you haven't got any conflicting flash players installed, like maybe gnash. - AFAIR, Chromium has it's own flash player built-in to the browser.

You could also try using [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) - an Firefox extension specifically for such a problem!.

Comment: did that before asking.

Comment: Double check that you haven't got any conflicting flash players installed, like maybe gnash. - AFAIR, Chromium has it's own flash player built-in to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I removed both and just installed gnash. Please put the comment about conflicting players in your answer just to clean things up a bit.